# Random unique identifiers with namespace for PostgreSQL

Tags: perl, random, uniqueidentifier, postgresql-9.2

I want to generate random unique IDs like (using Perl); 
 `XYZ2345672`, `ABC0098321`, `LMN_G8732415`

Pattern is
 `<prefix><[0-9]{7}>`

I have 5 such prefix. The ID should pass unique constraint in the database. How can I go about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new ID
2. check if this ID was already created (if so, repeat).

E.g.

```
use 5.010;

sub new_id_for_prefix {
  my $prefix = shift;
  state $seen = {};
  my $id;
  do { $id = $prefix . int rand(1E7) } while exists $seen->{$id};
  $seen->{$id} = undef;
  return $id;
}

say new_id_for_prefix("foo") for 1..5;
```

Example output:

```
foo2533460
foo1633946
foo6099891
foo8084746
foo4358492
```

If you want UIDs/GUIDs, then there are modules for that which you should use instead.

Comment: `$seen->{$id} = 1;` and `exists` can be dropped.

Comment: @mpapec Using `exists` is theoretically cheaper.

Comment: using `exists` is calling a function?

Comment: @mpapec I don't understand. `exists` is an operator, and has its own opcode. Anyway, I benchmarked it, and `exists` comes out 5% faster when the elements do not exist, otherwise they are the same speed-wise.

Comment: tnx for info; so internally it is an operator?

Comment: @mpapec All builtin functions are effectively operators, but some are more subroutine-like. `exists` is one that can't really be overridden.  `exists $foo->{key}` is different from a normal access that the access isn't actually executed. Instead, it looks if an entry is present. This is very different from normal subs where the arguments are always fully evaluated before the sub is called. See also `map 2*$_, ...`, where `map` is no ordinary sub: The first arg always becomes a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
{ 
my %uniq;
sub get_random_id {
  my ($prefix, $digits) = @_;

  my $ret;
  do {
    $ret = $prefix . join "", map { int rand(10) } 1 .. $digits;
  }
  while $uniq{$ret}++;

  return $ret;
}}

print get_random_id("ABC", 7), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's (at least) one CPAN module which can do this. `String::Random` allows you to generate random strings based on patterns, and it also allows you to define your own custom patterns. The example below defines an array of five possible strings for the custom `P` pattern. `n` is pre-defined and is replaced by random digits:

```
use String::Random;
my $rand = String::Random->new;
$rand->{P} = ["prefixA","prefixB","prefixC","prefixD","prefixE"];
print $rand->randpattern("Pnnnnnnn"), "\n";
```